# (reflexivity,symmetry,transitivity) relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Construct a smallest possible relation on the set {a, b, c, d} that is  irreflexive, symmetric, and transitive. I thought that the relation would be an empty set, R is symmetric because (a,b) can never belong to it and so the conditional statement is always true. R is transitive because (a,b) and (b,c) can never belong to it and so the conditional statement is always true.
do you think that there is anything wrong with my assumption?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440/why-isnt-reflexivity-redundant-in-the-definition-of-equivalence-relation

Comment: See also [\[1\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/65102/468350), [\[2\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872625/468350), and [\[3\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/268726/468350).  There are other examples which can be found by searching this site for the terms "symmetric transitive irreflexive" and/or variations on that theme.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: your link [2] is the one that actually provides an answer to this question. I don't think your other links are pertinent.

Comment: The duplicate addresses relations that are not reflexive (meaning there is at least one element $a$ in the set such that $(a, a) \notin R$.  However, if by irreflexive you mean that there is ***no*** $x \in \{a, b, c, d\}$ such that $(x, x) \in R$, then you are correct that such a relation can only be the empty relation $R = \{ \} = \varnothing.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that [there are in fact, non-empty relations that are *not* reflexive, but are symmetric and transitive.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872625/468350).

A relation $R$ that is not reflexive on a set $\{a, b, c\}$ means simply that one or more of $(a, a), (b, b), (c, c) \notin R$.

So, for example, $R_1 = \{(a, a), (a, b), (b, a), (b, b)\}$ is not reflexive (because $(c, c) \notin R_1$), but it is symmetric and transitive.

However, you stipulated in your question that you were wondering what a relation on a set could be that is  *irreflexive*, symmetric, and transitive would be.

A relation $R_2$ that is [*irreflexive*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiOxJD2ttfoAhUDWqwKHX9cBxcQFjALegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FIrreflexive.html&usg=AOvVaw1YCKQOu_WzeKXyT5uJ4Ln_) on a set $A$ is a relation for which there is no element $x\in A$, for which $(x, x) \in R$.  So, for example, in our previous example of a non-reflexive relation, we'd have to remove $(a, a), (b, b) \in R_2$.  If we remove $(a, a)$ and $(b, b)$ from $R_2$, then it ceases to be transitive, because we'd have $(a, b) \in R_2$, and $(b, a) \in R_2$ but not $(a, a), (b, b)\in R_2$. So we'd need to remove $(a, b), (b, a)$ from $R_2$.    Hence we are left with an empty set, $R_2 = \varnothing.$

So the only relation that is *irreflexive*, symmetric, and transitive, on any set, is in fact, the empty set.

Comment: Good as always, clear!

Comment: I think the site should manage a project to control Corona19 mathematically!